# PyQt TypeError connect()

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm very new to Python, so I'm sorry ahead of time if this is a simple mistake.

```
class TaskTabs(QtGui.QTabWidget):
    ...(some init stuff here)....
    def remove(self):
        self.removeTab(0)
        self.addTab(Tabs.General(self.nao, self.parent), 'General')
```

In another class:

```
self.taskTabs = TaskTabs(self.nao, mainWidget)
....(Some other stuff here)....
loadEmpathy = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon(), '&Load Empathy', self)
loadEmpathy.setShortcut('Ctrl+E')
loadEmpathy.triggered.connect(self.taskTabs.remove())
```

There error that I am getting is:

```
TypeError: connect() slot argument should be a callable or a signal, not 'NoneType'
```

What I am trying to do is to remove a tab in my GUI and add in various ones (which I'll implement later, just testing this now) from a menu. My menu code works perfectly, and now I want to set an action for what happens when it's clicked. I created this remove method in my TaskedTabs file, the remove function works great in my init function, but I want to separate it (for purposes later on). Can anyone explain what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says, `connect()` needs a callable method. But what you are giving it is the *result* of a method, because you're calling it. `remove()` returns `None`, which is then used as the argument for `connect()`, which doesn't work. Solve this by removing the brackets after `remove`.

```
loadEmpathy.triggered.connect(self.taskTabs.remove)
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining it, works perfectly. I probably should of tried that myself before asking, but thanks nonetheless.