# i can't clicked.connect() QPushButton on QFormLayout

Tags: python, pyqt5

this is the full code, i don't know why i can't use that clicked.connect on my mind, that's still logic '-' but why!!!???

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QScrollArea, QVBoxLayout, QGroupBox, QLabel, QPushButton, QFormLayout
import sys


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, val):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = "PyQt5 Scroll Bar"
        self.top = 200
        self.left = 500
        self.width = 400
        self.height = 300
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("icon.png"))
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

    formLayout = QFormLayout()
    groupBox = QGroupBox("This Is Group Box")
    labelLis = []
    comboList = []
    for i in range(val):
        labelLis.append(QLabel("Label"))
        comboList.append(QPushButton("Click Me").clicked.connect(print("hello")))
        formLayout.addRow(labelLis[i], comboList[i])
    groupBox.setLayout(formLayout)

    scroll = QScrollArea()
    scroll.setWidget(groupBox)
    scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
    scroll.setFixedHeight(400)
    layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
    layout.addWidget(scroll)
    self.show()


App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window(30)
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

and i got error in here, i wanna make every each item can clicked, but i don't know why this happen :"D

```
for i in range(val):
        labelLis.append(QLabel("Label"))
        comboList.append(QPushButton("Click Me").clicked.connect(print("hello")))
        formLayout.addRow(labelLis[i], comboList[i])
    groupBox.setLayout(formLayout)
```

> this code not working, `comboList.append(QPushButton("Click Me").clicked.connect(print("hello")))`

Comment: Signals expect a *callable* as argument. `print()` returns `None`, which obviously is **not** a callable. Marked as duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/q/16696684] Also, you're *not* appending the button to the `comboList`, but the result of `connect()`, which will be `None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t know why `comboList.append(QPushButton("Click Me").clicked.connect(self.hello)` error occurs

But i will do

```
qbutton = QPushButton("Click Me")
qbutton.clicked.connect(self.hello)
```

result

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QScrollArea, QVBoxLayout, QGroupBox, QLabel, QPushButton, QFormLayout
import sys


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, val):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = "PyQt5 Scroll Bar"
        self.top = 200
        self.left = 500
        self.width = 400
        self.height = 300
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("icon.png"))
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        formLayout = QFormLayout()
        groupBox = QGroupBox("This Is Group Box")
        labelLis = []
        comboList = []

        for i in range(val):
            qbutton = QPushButton("Click Me")
            qbutton.clicked.connect(self.hello)
            labelLis.append(QLabel("Label"))
            comboList.append(qbutton)
            formLayout.addRow(labelLis[i], comboList[i])

        groupBox.setLayout(formLayout)

        scroll = QScrollArea()
        scroll.setWidget(groupBox)
        scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        scroll.setFixedHeight(400)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(scroll)
        self.show()

    def hello(self):
        print('hello')


App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window(30)
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Comment: The difference is very clear: `print('hello')` returns `None`, while `self.hello` (which is without parentheses) is a reference to a callable.